# Android third part media library

Tags: android, video, video-player

I'm playing video from Url in my app. At the moment I'm using Android's `videoView` but to improve the performance I prefer to use a third part media library. I tried Vitamio but when I add the library it add at least 10MB to the apk and makes it too big.
I just wonder if anyone has any suggestion or know any good quality third part media library.
Thanks in Advance